# python - dataframe - groupby - treatment of non-grouped column in case of difference

Tags: python, pandas, pandas-groupby

I have a dataframe containing an ID and I wish to 'group by' based on the ID. I need to keep all other columns (static data,strings) of the dataframe as well, so initially I included all static data columns in the group by. However, there can be differences in the static data between 2 or more rows that have the same ID (due to different source). In that case I would still like to group on the ID and not create 'duplicates'. For the column having the difference I'm rather indifferent, the grouped row can just take the first one it encounters of the conflicting rows.

Hope this illustration clarifies:

[example](https://i.stack.imgur.com/sOsTU.png)

Any suggestions?

Comment: so you want a unique data.frame , and 1 entry per group?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use `groupby().agg()` and specify what you want to do which each column in your dataframe within a dictionary. Based on the example of your intended outcome that would be:

```
df.groupby('identifier').agg({'name': 'first', 'amount':'sum'})
```

It takes the first value of the `name` columns and it `sums` the values in the `amount` column.